# Prove, in this figure, that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

> In the following figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, and $O$ is *any* point. Parallelograms $OAEB, OBFC, OCGD, ODHA$ are completed. Prove that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram.[image]

We can obtain a fairly trivial proof using affine geometry. As $OAEB, OBFC, OCGD, ODHA$ are parallelograms,

$$\vec{A} + \vec{B} = \vec{O} + \vec{E} \implies \vec{A}  + \vec{B} - \vec{O} = \vec{E} \tag1$$

$$\vec{C} + \vec{B} - \vec{O} = \vec{F}\tag2$$

$$\vec{D} + \vec{C} - \vec{O} = \vec{G} \tag3$$

$$\vec{D} + \vec{A} - \vec{O} = \vec{H}\tag4$$

Adding $(1)$ to $(3)$ and $(2)$ to $(4)$, we get,

$$\vec{E} + \vec{G} = \vec{A} + \vec{B} + \vec{C} + \vec{D} - 2\vec{O} \tag5$$

$$\vec{F} + \vec{H} =  \vec{A} + \vec{B} + \vec{C} + \vec{D} - 2\vec{O} \tag6$$

Clearly, $(5)$ and $(6)$ are equal, therefore,

$$\vec{E} + \vec{G} = \vec{F} + \vec{H}$$

Therefore, $EFGH$ is a parallelogram. Can somebody give an elementary proof using Euclidean geometry? Also, I noticed that in my proof, nowhere did I use the fact that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, but constructing an example, it was quickly clear that the result stated does not generalize to all quadrilaterals. How come? Is my proof incorrect?

Comment: I think your proof is correct and the statement *"it was quickly clear that the result stated does not generalize to all quadrilaterals"* may be wrong.  Furthermore, the dimensions of $EFGH$ do not depend on $O$, though the location does: e.g. $\vec{E} - \vec{F} =  \vec{A} - \vec{C}$

Comment: Your proof looks fine, which means that the result *doesn't* require $ABCD$ to be a parallelogram. (A quick experiment with GeoGebra confirms that for me. Perhaps your follow-up construction was flawed?)

Comment: @Blue: Yes, you're right. I had tried the construction with GeoGebra too. I see now where I went wrong.

Comment: Here's a hint for an elementary geometry proof (with any quadrilateral): Dilate $EFGH$ with respect to $O$, using scale factor $1/2$.

Comment: To extend my previous comment: the sides of the final parallelogram are translations of the diagonals of the original quadrilateral.  The area of the final parallelogram is twice the area of the original quadrilateral

Comment: @Blue: Could you elaborate your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known (and easily provable) that the "mid-point polygon" of any quadrilateral is a parallelogram. (Opposite sides are parallel to a diagonal.) The Question's $EFGH$ is simply the dilation of the mid-point polygon with respect to point $O$, with scale factor $2$, and is therefore also a parallelogram.

[image]

Comment: How did you see that $EFGH$ was a scale $2$ dilation of the mid-point polygon of $ABCD$?

Comment: @Gerard: Well, the realization wasn't immediate. (I initially had to make the GeoGebra simulation to verify that $EFGH$ was a parallelogram.) But, as I ticked-through observations about the figure ---like that $\triangle OAB \cong \triangle EAB$--- I noted that the simplest route from $O$ to $E$ was through the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ ---and not just *through* it, but as a *reflection in it*--- and that seems to have triggered the "Ah-ha!" moment.

Comment: Amazing solution, once you see the simplicity of it.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG O is the origin, and let $a = \vec{OA}$ (define $b, c, \dots , h$) similarly.
Then $e=a+b$, $f=b+c$, $g=c+d$ and $h=d+a$.
Note that $\frac{e+g}{2}=\frac{f+h}{2}=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$. So EG and FH have the same midpoint, and so EFGH is a parallelogram.